# Profiles in maven - select file to build in depends on profile in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have `application.properties` file.  I would like to be able to use another `application.properties` file in depends on chosen profile in maven.   Can you show me how to do this ?

Above is my idea for this problem.  Maybe you know something better?  I mean problem of chosing jdbc connection.  It means that depending on profile I would like to be able to choose different jdbc urls.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <!-- This profile will be default in your IDE -->
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-dev</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>

        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-prod</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You will need to create two directories: `src/main/resources-dev` and `src/main/resources-prod`. Then put a corresponding `application.properties` to each directory:

```
src
   main
      java
         ...
   resources-dev
      application.properties
   resources-prod
      application.properties
```

Command to build with `dev` profile: `mvn clean install`

Command to
   build with `prod` profile: `mvn clean install -Pprod`

Comment: does it means two almost the same `application.prpoerties` files ?

Comment: @JavaNewbie If there is really much duplication you can use one `application.properties` with filtering: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Can you show me example of such filtering here, please ?

Comment: @JavaNewbie This was already discussed on SO many times. Try to use search.

Answer (score 0):

While technically this is very easy and you can refer to the answer of @ZhekaKozlov, this is a very bad idea. If the password to DB changes, should the application itself change? No - the app stays the same, it's the configuration of the app that changes.

By using Maven Profiles you're creating a new binary for different environments which effectively means - new app for each configuration option. So instead of doing this you can choose 2 options:

- If allowed you can put all the configuration files inside of the binary and then choose between them during startup (`-Denv=prd`). But you'd still have to build a new binary in case property changes.
- The best option is externalizing the configuration from the binary. Meaning during startup you specify the location of the properties file: `-Dconf=/etc/appname/application.properties`.

The golden rule of Continuous Delivery - build once run everywhere. You should always be able to download the binary from any of the envs and run it locally with a different set of properties.

Comment: Sometimes it can be a security hole. Development builds can include sensitive files which should not be on production servers. Also, you forgot about desktop applications whete possibility to run in dev mode by end users is inappropriate.

Comment: I don't understand your point.. It looks like you didn't understand mine :) I'm saying that configs should be located _outside_ of the binary. They have to be deployed _to the server_ by the deployment scripts. The very same deployment scripts would download the binary as well.